# python convert str to javascript literal string

Tags: javascript, python

I want to use python to generate javascript code dynamiclly.

```
def convert(jsstring=''):
    return 'function dosomething () { return %s.toLowerCase(); }' % jsstring
```

The problem is `jsstring` is a python string.

How can i convert it back to javascript string literal to make `dosomething` a valid javascript function ?

for example

call

```
convert("javascript")
```

now output

```
 function dosomething () { return javascript.toLowerCase(); }
```

which is not a valid javascript function

expected output

```
 function dosomething () { return "javascript".toLowerCase(); }
```

another example, call

```
convert("javascript\'")
```

expected output

```
 function dosomething () { return "javascript\'".toLowerCase(); }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is "python string lexical"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
import json

jsstring = """
    foo "bar"
"""

print 'function dosomething () { return %s.toLowerCase(); }' % json.dumps(jsstring)
```

Suggested `repr` won't work with unicode strings:

```
jsstring = u"\u1234"
print 'function dosomething () { return %s.toLowerCase(); }' % repr(jsstring)
```

returns

```
function dosomething () { return u'\u1234'.toLowerCase(); }
```

which is not valid javascript.

Comment: Using json here just for string quoting is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: @CiroSantilli: `json.dumps` uses `ensure_ascii=True` by default, so weird unicodes are not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding appropriate quotes around `%s`, i.e.:

```
'function dosomething () { return "%s".toLowerCase(); }' % jsstring
```

Here's a command-line session to clarify the difference:

```
In [10]: joe = 'somestring'

In [11]: '%s.toLowerCase();' % joe
Out[11]: 'somestring.toLowerCase();'

In [12]: '"%s".toLowerCase();' % joe
Out[12]: '"somestring".toLowerCase();'
```

Comment: not that simple. how about convert("javascript\'"). the return will be 'javascript ''.toLowerCase(); it illegal in javascript

Answer (score 2):

Step through your code:

```
def convert(jsstring=''):
    return 'function dosomething () { return %s.toLowerCase(); }' % jsstring
```

Now, if `jsstring` is `"Foo"`, what does it produce?

```
function dosomething () { return Foo.toLowerCase(); }
```

Of course this will fail. There is no variable called `Foo` set in the javascript function.

In all likelihood, you wanted a string literal:

```
def convert(jsstring=''):
    return 'function dosomething () { return "%s".toLowerCase(); }' % jsstring
```

Of course, you'll need to make sure nothing goes wrong if `jsstring` includes quotes, linebreaks and other sensitive characters. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: should get them on the right track. Don't have unlimited time.

Answer (score 2):

Use repr inside string interpolation:

```
>>> 'This is a string: %r' % ('python string')
'This is a string: "python string"'
```

So just replace %s with %r in your code. `repr()` will do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You better quote the string appropriately what ever you are passing to the function. This will keep things simple

For the example mentioned

```
>>> convert('"javascript"')
'function dosomething () { return "javascript".toLowerCase(); }'
```

And if you want to pass a quoted string, escape it appropiately

```
>>> print convert("\"javascript\"\"")
function dosomething () { return "javascript"".toLowerCase(); }
```

And  remember if you want the raw representation, always use `repr`, you will get what you are intending

```
>>> repr(convert("\"javascript\"\""))
'\'function dosomething () { return "javascript"".toLowerCase(); }\''
```

or to keep it transparent, add the repr inside the function.

```
>>> def convert(jsstring=''):
    return repr('function dosomething () { return %s.toLowerCase(); }' % jsstring)

>>> convert("\"javascript\"\"")
'\'function dosomething () { return "javascript"".toLowerCase(); }\''
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `repr`, or else your string will not work if it contains " or '. For example:

```
... % repr(jsstring)
```

Failure to use `repr` may also be a security vulnerability (via injection of " or ' or other characters). Failure to use `repr` may also cause your javascript to fail if your string contains those characters. Though if security is a concern, you will also want to avoid text like `</script>`, and other things, by putting it through a proper escaping system, or encode it in something like base64.